# Syntax Highlighting for ABAP

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

So far I made some posts about [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), etc.

I always like to use the "code samples" block which marks text as code and provides syntax highlighting.

Unfortunately this does not work with ABAP code. If the highlighter already exists, can it be added to the by Stack Exchange supported languages?